# Select page path CSS in DNN

Tags: css

I'm working in DNN in the stylesheet to overrule a specific standardstyled button. This is working code to overrule the styling and change it into what I want, but it changes it for all buttons.

```
@import url("Templates/htmlEditorTemplates.css");
.threeCol .Normal a {
    color: #000000;
    float: right;
    line-height: 3;
}
```

I understand that this code changes it for all because i specified .threecol .Normal a, which specifies all buttons I made. I only want a specific button on a page to change, in order to do that I have to select the button location. how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that by adding a class (i.e. `special-link`) to those links you want to target and give them its own rule.

HTML

```
<a class="special-link">...</a>
```

CSS

```
.threeCol .Normal a.special-link {
    color: #000000;
    float: right;
    line-height: 3;
}
```